# Forming a committee of 4 (1 president, 3 equal roles) from 20 people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a question that goes:
How many different ways are there to form a committee of 4 members from a total of 20 faculty members, if one of them is distinct, e.g. chair of the committee, and the other 3 have the same role?

Am I correct in solving this as $\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{3}$, as there are 20 ways to select one chair of the committee, and 19 ways to select other three roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the wording of the question is ambiguous. If the chair is known in advance than there are $\binom{19}{3}$ ways of choosing the other 3 members of the committee. But if the chair is not known in advance then the answer is $\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{3}$.

Comment: Well that's a better way to put it!